# Running a local server on Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to run a local rails server on Jenkins and have another job make use of localhost. I was thinking of using the Multijob plugin and having one job start a server and another job use localhost in whatever way but I'm not sure how well this would work especially because I don't know how I would stop the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a [rails server](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server) as daemon in:

*Build* → *Add build step* → *Execute shell* → *Command*: `rails server -d`

To stop it you can use [`pkill`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pkill.htm) in:

*Post-build Actions* → *Add post-build action* → *Execute a set of scripts* → *Add a shell or a Windows batch file* → *Batch or a shell script files to execute* → *File script path:* `<your kill script>`